# insertable=false not working inside an Embeddable which is mapped in an ElemenCollection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity called Parent which has an ElementCollection of Child (which is defined as Embeddable).
 
Child has an attribute called `serialNo` which is mapped as follows:

```
@Column(name = "sr_no",insertable=false)<br>
private int serialNo;
```

However, when I persist Parent, I can see that the `sr_no` column is included in the resultant insert statements for the Child table.
Does insertable not work when used in this context?

Comment: Is the data from column "sr_no" mapped also from another java field? Do you have a default value for the column in DB?

Comment: Andrei, Yes I have a auto increment column in my postgres DB for that column and that is why I want insertable to be false.

Comment: Can you show us the entire entity please?